# Unexplained and persistent "OS X 10.13 is not supported" dialog

Tags: macos, software-update, malware

I am being interrupted multiple times a day by a mysterious dialog box that says:

"OS X 10.13 is not supported. There is an update but you are on OS X 10.13 or an earlier version. Upgrade to the latest version of macOS to install it."

While I was considering doing the OS update soon, this dialog has actually caused me to hesitate, because I can find absolutely no documentation for it. A google search gives only a *single* hit, and that is in French. I am a bit concerned that this could be evidence of malware- perhaps, for example, the running an update could give malware a special opportunity to get extra permissions/control of my system.

Does anyone have an idea where such a dialog could be coming from, or what app may be triggering it? Image attached.

[image: Recurring, unexplained dialog box]

Update: here is the one (french) link I found on the internet which may reference the same dialog box. No useful information there, as far as I can tell:

https://communities.apple.com/fr/thread/251948653

Comment: Can you add the link to the page you found via Google? Did you check whether one of your applications or login items needs to be updated?

Comment: Something you are running in the background  needs to be updated.  To confirm, boot into Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting). If it goes away, it's a 3rd party app that needs to be updated.

Comment: @Allan, thanks. I will try that now. Can you confirm, then, that this dialog box is an authentic Apple software feature?

Comment: @nohillside, thanks. I checked some of my apps but not all. I'll do a more extensive investigation on that now!

Comment: Confirm what?  A dialog box is real?  A notification doesn't have to be generated by macOS to be genuine; any app can create a notification.  In this case an app could be complaining that it's no longer compatible with the OS you're running.

Comment: I wonder if Activity Monitor would show the owner of that dialog box, helping to run down the culprit?

Comment: Problem solved! It was a 3rd party app (Docker), installed as part of a different application suite. Oddly, the app preferences had it set to run upon login, but I didn't find Docker listed in the Sys Pref Users and Groups/login items. Anyway, thanks for your thoughtful comments.

Comment: @ChuckSindelar Thanks! I was also wondering what that was. I'm able to confirm it's Docker by manually doing 'Check for updates...'. They really should have included their app name in that message..

Comment: @SteveChambers One would have to run through all of the applications and quit them one by one to see which one closes the dialog.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is with the docker application.

Comment: Confirmed - when I force quit Docker from the Activity Monitor, the prompt goes away.

Answer (score 9):

This comes from Docker.  Click the docker icon in the bar and choose `Preferences`.  Go to the `Software Updates` section and uncheck `Automatically check for updates`.  Click `Apply & Restart`.  It should go away after changing this setting.

Comment: Thanks. This seemed to solve it for me.

Comment: Note that turning off _Automatically check for updates_ does not work in all cases (including mine). See [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5150) in the Docker for Mac GitHub.

Comment: There is no "Automatically check for updates" in Docker for Mac v3.0.3 unfortunately